# Prompt out Invalid Character error when use query on behind code

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm need to write a query at backend code and call it from that.
but it will hit the error "invalid character" when I call it.

If I straight run the same query at *Oracle SQL Developer*, it can run successfully.

The query is like at below:

```
SELECT LOOM_GROUP, DESCRIPTION, '1', Created_By, Created_Date, Updated_by, Updated_date
FROM MSO_Loom_Group 
WHERE to_char(CREATED_DATE,'yyyymmdd') >= (to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2))+1,'yyyymmdd'))
OR to_char(UPDATED_DATE,'yyyymmdd') >= (to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2))+1,'yyyymmdd'));
```

Comment: can please post your back end code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the **semi colon(;)** at the end in code behind. While it is valid in oracle, it gives error if we keep it in code behind.